# Unable to run two applications simultaniously in Java 6 and Java 8 using jnlp

Tags: java, java-8, java-web-start, java-6

We have two applications launched using Java Web Start (jnlp file) and each application supporting different java version. One application supports Java/JRE 1.6 (supports java 1.5 but not Java 1.7 or 1.8) and the other supports Java/JRE 1.8 (only).

When we try to launch both the applications on the same desktop using direct JNLP links e.g. `<serveraddress>/deploymentfolder/abc.jnlp`, looks like the JavaWS cache gets corrupt and the applications are not working as expected.

We tried several methods of launching the applications listed below. In all cases, we configure two different .bat files to launch each application using complete java path e.g.

```
C:\java\jre1.6\javaws http://serveraddress/deploymentfolder/app1.jnlp
```

and

```
C:\java\jre1.8\javaws http://serveraddress2/deploymentfolder/app2.jnlp
```

### Methods

1. Install JRE 1.6 using Java installer, use a copy-only (no need to install) copy of Java 1.8.
2. Install JRE 1.8 and used a copy-only copy of JRE 1.6
3. Install both versions
4. Use copy-only version of both versions
5. Along with first four methods, we tried to configure different JavaWS cache folder for different version by specifying it in deployment.properties file.

We could not get both the application running successfully in any try. In application logs, we see exceptions suggesting the cache is corrupt (pasted below).

Can anyone please suggest any ideas on how we can get these two applications running?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: ERROR: Failed to recover corrupt cache entry
at com.sun.deploy.cache.CacheEntry.recover(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.CacheEntry.getCodeSourceCache(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.CachedJarFile.getCodeSourceCache(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.CachedJarFile.findMatchingSignerIndices(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.CachedJarFile.entryNames(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.DeployCacheJarAccessImpl.entryNames(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.CPCallbackHandler.assertTrust(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.CPCallbackHandler.access$700(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.CPCallbackHandler$ParentCallback.check(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.CPCallbackHandler$ParentCallback.access$1500(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.CPCallbackHandler$ChildElement.checkResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.checkResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getResource(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
....
....
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.windowClosing(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.windowClosing(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.windowClosing(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.windowClosing(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.windowClosing(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.processWindowEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JFrame.processWindowEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: I have not gone into much direct testing on the theory, but questions I've dealt with in recent times *suggest* to me that Oracle has ceased supporting the use of an older JRE for a JWS app. If Java 1.8 ever gets hold of the JNLP, intended for 1.5/1.6, it is likely it won't relinquish the app. to the control of a 1.6 JRE (and is thereby the source of this dilemma). What is it that limits the app. to 1.5/1.6? Has it been tested and shown to fail in 1.7/1.8?